# Using C#, what is the best way to validate a public key / address?

Tags: key

The link here [What is the best method for key validation?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/209/what-is-the-best-method-for-key-validation) has an answer for JS, and an answer for calculating it yourself, of which I have can't understand because I don't have a deep CS background.

There's no such feature in https://github.com/QuantozTechnology/csharp-stellar-base or https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple method for elucidsoft SDK:

```
bool IsAccountIdValid(string accountId) {
    if (!String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(encoded) && encoded.Length != 56) return false;

    try {
        var decoded = StrKey.DecodeStellarAccountId(accountId);
        if (decoded.Length !== 32) return false;    
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want to check the validity of a secret key, just change `DecodeStellarAccountId` to `DecodeStellarSecretSeed`.